# Event sourcing access by reference

Tags: microservices, enterprise-architecture, architectural-patterns, event-sourcing, pubsub

In an event sourcing architecture, what is the typical pattern for passing information about related objects (aggregates)?

For example, in a order processing system, should `OrderCreated` event (published by the `OrderService)` contain `productId` or a `Product`?

Assuming there's also a `ProductService`), with the first option, receivers of the event can call the `ProductService` to get the `Product` and with the second option  all the information it needs are already in the event. But I'm not quite clear on the pros and cons of the two approaches. Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Your `productId` is only a handle to the `Product` instance itself.  This may or may not be useful on its own.  For instance if you want to persist something to the database, and you require only the `productId`, then there is no need to provide also the entire `Product` instance.

That said, in all likelihood you probably will need the `Product` instance and all the data that comes with it.  This complicates serialization of the event should you require it, but you'd need only to find a way to serialize the `productId` itself, which can be solved using a technical solution.  Aside from this, there is no real reason why you wouldn't simply provide the `Product` instance itself.  If the `ProductService` is required in other contexts, then you'd need both, otherwise the service is not necessary and can be removed.  In other words, you don't have to pick between one *or* the other.  If you require both `ProductService` as well as passing the instance of `Product`, then keep both.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. ProductService is not a property in the event, but a microservice which has an API that returns a Product given productId

Comment: @ubi I had understood it this way.  I didn't mean you'd need to *pass* both in the event.  In a looser sense, I meant you don't have to get rid of the ProductService just because you pass a Product instance in your event (since you wouldn't need it for those requiring Product at least pertaining to that event).